# add a nn.Parameter tensor to the optim

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

let's say I have a network with a parameter tensor:

```
self.inital_value = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1,96,4,4))
```

and two layers:

```
self.rgb_layers = nn.ModuleList([nn.Conv2d(96, 3, 1, 1, 0)]*2)
```

so the forward function is as follows:

```
v = torch.clone(self.inital_value)
for i in range(2):
    v = self.rgb_layers[i](v)
return v
```

now I define an optimiser. if I want to train only the first layer I can do:

```
opt = optim.RMSprop(model.rgb_layers[0].parameters(),lr = lr)
```

but if I want to train only the tensor `self.inital_value` and I do the same I get this error:

```
'Parameter' object has no attribute 'parameters'
```

how can I bypass this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it takes a sequence of `Parameter`s. And you have one `Parameter`, called `self.initial_value`.

So how about `[self.initial_value]` ?

Comment: isn't 'nn.Parameter(Tensor)' a tensor of many parameters, and not a single parameter?

Comment: @MoranReznik parameter != `nn.Parameter`

Comment: I don't understand, really :)

Comment: @MoranReznik a parameter is a number. a `Parameter` is an object that includes many parameters. I never mentioned a "parameter" in my answer, by the way.